# Determine type of archive file in Linux

Tags: linux, download, compression, tar

I have an archive file with `.tar.gz` as extension grabbed from http://www.oracle.com (it is the Java Runtime Environment). I tried to decompress it using `tar -xvf` and `tar -zxvf` and it says `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`. I can open it without any kind of trouble in WinRar on Windows, but it doesn't say much about the type of container it uses.

I looked up in google and some people were saying that those archives were badly compressed and needs to be fixed, but I can't figure out how to "fix it".

Is it possible to find more information about it using some kind of command in Linux? Thanks.

The file I am talking about is this one: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u67-b01/server-jre-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: Are you sure you mean ".gz.tar"? Normally the ".tar" comes *before* the ".gz". Please edit your question if this is just a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You use the [file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) command - which should tell you what it is. However, grabbing the file from that link downloads an error page, and I don't have an oracle login.

Answer (score 0):

It was a really silly mistake, I was expecting a `.tar.gz` but as I didn't accept the ToS of Oracle it downloaded a html saying something in the lines of "you must accept the conditions before accepting the file", I was actually trying to decompress that (which wasn't a valid file).

It worked on Windows because I did accept the ToS in the page itself.